# Is there a way to record all "point down" (i.e. which points are touched, such as those registered by resting your palm on the screen) in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I understand that gesture recognizers are based on UITouch-es (representing fingers) and UIEvent-s (representing touch sequences).

Is there a way to know which points on the screens have been touched? Suppose I'd like to take a handprint of the user, can I do that?

clarify:
I mean ALL points - now just those registered by UITouch - which represents fingers.
E.g. if my palm is resting on the screen, can I register those points under my palm as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can get touch point by this method `- (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view` which is belonging to UITouch event.

You can get touch event by following methods.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is a UITouch method. So that means it corresponds to a finger. Suppose I have a palm resting on the screen, and I'd like to record which part of the screen is the user resting on, UITouch won't allow me to do that.

Comment: You know . this is your question `Is there a way to know which points on the screens have been touched?`

Comment: yes - ALL points. not just those that corresponds to fingers - which is what UITouch represents.

Comment: Did you see this method `touchesBegan:`. It will return set of touch event, each will have different touch point. You've to workaround with this point as you like.

Comment: Mani, UITouch is designed to register fingers. So, the points has been preprocessed and modelled to determine the finger position. Our fingers are fatter than 1 point, and many points are touched when we tap the screen. Preprocessing and modelling has to be done to reduce those points to 1 point. I'm looking to record all those points before preprocessing and modelling. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: @kev Thank you friend. Make me clear. I just go through some doc to learn about this. If you got answer for this , post your own answer. :)

Comment: Thanks Mani. Will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine multi-touch events with CSS visual effects to enable dragging or some other user action. To enable dragging, implement the touchmove event handler to translate the target:

```
function touchMove(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    curX = event.targetTouches[0].pageX - startX;
    curY = event.targetTouches[0].pageY - startY;
    event.targetTouches[0].target.style.webkitTransform =
        'translate(' + curX + 'px, ' + curY + 'px)';
}
```

Typically, you implement multi-touch event handlers to track one or two touches. But you can also use multi-touch event handlers to identify custom gestures. That is, custom gestures that are not already identified for you by gesture events described in “Handling Gesture Events.” For example, you can identify a two-finger tap gesture as follows:

Begin gesture if you receive a touchstart event containing two target touches.
End gesture if you receive a touchend event with no preceding touchmove events.
Similarly, you can identify a swipe gesture as follows:

Begin gesture if you receive a touchstart event containing one target touch.
Abort gesture if, at any time, you receive an event with >1 touches.
Continue gesture if you receive a touchmove event mostly in the x-direction.
Abort gesture if you receive a touchmove event mostly the y-direction.
End gesture if you receive a touchend event.

Comment: you can see this [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html]

Comment: that's web app coding. Not an native IOS app. Am I right?